# How to remove selection 'border' from flash objects

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash

I'm having difficulties with trying to remove a 'border' that appears on some flash objects I'm importing into some div's.

It seems like the browser (I can only test in IE) is putting some kind of selection border on every object.

I've already tried the following:

```
css - border:0 and outline: 0
html - hidefocus="true"
```

which didn't help.

Due to company policies I cannot show the urls which I'm getting the flash objects from, but here's the html element I'm inserting one of them into:

```
<div id="graphs" style="border:0;outline:0;height:510px;width:100%;z-index:1;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;">  
</div>
```

Here's a link to the screenshot of the outputted elements: (content is hidden due to company policies)

[Screenshot Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u7qaa3nhrhbjz4h/selectionborder.jpg)

Hope you guys can help me out, thanks in advance!

Comment: Try border:none; instead of 0

Comment: In CSS use like this `object {outline:none;}`. let me know if it works?

Comment: Thanks for the reply' I've already tried border:none and outline:none which didn't work.  I've also tried using !important with no effect

Comment: As an extreme hack (just for testing!) does `* { border: none !important; outline: none !important; }` have any affect?

Comment: Nope I've just tried it, but thanks for the advice!
It seems to have something to do with the flash objects itself, which is seems to be some kind of code applying the effect. Since I don't have access to the flash files, it doesn't seem to be a solution. But thanks guys!